# How to write a wsgen script for Windows 

Tags: windows, soap, wsgen

I'm working on [Build a SOAP Server with GAE](http://code.google.com/intl/zh-TW/appengine/articles/soap.html#sv).
In the article, it contains...

> Run wsgen on the annoted class. This
>   tool is now included in the JDK. My
>   JDK includes the version from JAX-WS
>   RI 2.1.6. (You can discover the
>   version by typing wsgen -version.)
>   Because wsgen has several command-line
>   arguments, **I have written a Linux
>   shell script called runwsgen.sh to
>   execute it. If you are not using
>   Linux, you will have to translate this
>   script to your OS scripting language.**
>   Place the following script in the root
>   directory of the project (i.e. the
>   parent directory of war and src) and
>   execute it from there.

runwsgen.sh

```
class=com.example.Greeter
clpth='./war/WEB-INF/classes'
resourcedir='./war'
outsourcedir='./src'
outdir='./war/WEB-INF/classes'
wsgen -cp "$clpth" -wsdl -keep -r "$resourcedir" -d "$outdir" -s "$outsourcedir"  $class
```

My problem is how could I translate it to Windows script.
Thanks for any advice.

Comment: What does this have to do with App Engine? You mention it in the subject, but I don't see any connection.

Comment: Not a problem, but you haven't answered the question. I'm removing the tag on the assumption it's not related.

Comment: Because I encounter this problem when I working on "Build a SOAP Server with GAE", and the script above is also for GAE web project too. So I think maybe someone may encounter this problem while they are doing GAE.

Answer (score 3):

this may comes as really late answer, but hopefully it will be useful for other people out there.  you'd better build your project before run this script.

```
set class=com.example.Greeter
set clpth=./war/WEB-INF/classes
set resourcedir=./war
set outsourcedir=./src
set outdir=./war/WEB-INF/classes
wsgen -cp "%clpth%" -wsdl -keep -r "%resourcedir%" -d "%outdir%" -s "%outsourcedir%"  %class%
```

Answer (score -1):

```
class=com.example.Greeter
clpth='war/WEB-INF/classes'
resourcedir='war'
outsourcedir='src'
outdir='war/WEB-INF/classes'
wsgen -cp $clpth -wsdl -keep -r $resourcedir -d $outdir -s $outsourcedir  $class
```

Comment: You'd best elaborate on your answer. As it stands it's too short.

Comment: that doesn't seem to be a windows (shell) script